# C TCP/IP Sockets: How to synchronise input from client sockets to a server socket to be alternating

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client-server

I have a program that ultimately I want to make into a tic-tac-toe client-server game, but I am currently just testing the communication with sending and printing messages. I am okay up to the point of the server receiving messages from multiple clients, but the whole thing fails when I try to force it to alternate between clients, as in take input from client 1, then client 2, then 1 again etc. I am sure I am just going about it in a very wrong way.

Here is the code forming the connections and communicating with the clients.

```
listen(sockfd,5);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);


//client1
clientsockfd[0] = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
if (clientsockfd[0] < 0) {
  perror("ERROR on accept");
  exit(1);
}

//client2
clientsockfd[1] = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
if (clientsockfd[1] < 0) {
  perror("ERROR on accept");
  exit(1);
}

while (1) {

  //create child process for each client
  pid1 = fork();
  if (pid1 < 0) {
     perror("ERROR on fork");
     exit(1);
  }

  //client1
  if (pid1 == 0) {
     /* This is the client process */
     close(sockfd);
     doprocessing(clientsockfd[i]);

  }
  //client2
  if(pid2 == 0){
      close(sockfd);
      doprocessing(clientsockfd[i]);
      //functions
  }

  i++;
```

}

I also tried forking for the second time inside the first fork but it also failed.

Here is the part of client.c concerning the communication with the server.

```
 if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
   perror("Error connecting: ");
   exit(1);
}

while(1){

      //ask for message to be read by server
      printf("Please enter the message: ");
      bzero(buffer,256);
      fgets(buffer,255,stdin);

      // send message
      n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));

      if (n < 0) {
         perror("Error writing to socket: ");
         exit(1);
      }

      //empty buffer
      bzero(buffer,256);

      //read reply from server
      n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
      if (n < 0) {
         perror("Error reading from socket: ");
         exit(1);
      }

      printf("%s\n",buffer);
}
return 0;
}
```

Also here is the doprocessing function in case it is necessary

```
void doprocessing (int sock) {
int n;
char buffer[256];
bzero(buffer,256);
n = read(sock,buffer,255);

if (n < 0) {
  perror("ERROR reading from socket");
  exit(1);
}

printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
n = write(sock,"I got your message",18);

if (n < 0) {
  perror("ERROR writing to socket");
  exit(1);
}

}
```

What I get when running the program is: Upon the connection of the second client, there is an endless loop, where:

> ERROR reading from socket: Bad file descriptor

is repeated many times, then:

> ERROR on fork: recourse temporarily unavailable

appears twice, and finally:

> ERROR reading from socket:Input/output error

is repeated endlessly till I force-terminate the program.
If I have omitted any info necessary, please let me know and I will add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    while (1) {
        pid = fork();
        ....
        i++;
    }
```

creates too many child processes, eventually causing failure to fork.

Each child uses `clientsockfd[i]`; only two of them are actually allocated. Meanwhile `i` grows towards infinity; the third process already gets a garbage socket (it is also an out-of-bound access, therefore UB), which explains IO errors.

Consider instead forking the clients once, and

```
    while (1) {
       doprocessing(clientsockfd[0]);
       doprocessing(clientsockfd[1]);
    }
```

in the mainline.

Comment: Oh okay, I see why this wasnt working, I did not adjust it the right way from the simple version. Thank you. However, because in the final project I will need to include a fifo for each client, and do much more than call doprocessing(socket), where should I open the child processes? (if(!pid) {...}) In the while loop?